# Counting words in a word count program from filename

Tags: c, linux

I seem to be able to get the lines, characters and spaces correctly. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to count words. They don't have to be in dictionary form; for example, `fdasf fdjsak fea` would be three words.

This is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int ccount = 0;
  int wcount = 1;
  int lcount = 0;
  int scount = 0;

  char* filename = argv[1];
  printf("filename is: %s\n", filename);

  FILE* infile;
  infile = fopen(filename, "r");

  if (infile == NULL) {
    printf("%s: is not a valid file\n", filename);
    return -1;
  }

  char c;
  while ((c = fgetc(infile)) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' ') {
      wcount++;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
      lcount++;
    }
    if (c != ' ' || c != '\n') {
      ccount++;
    }
    if (c == ' ') {
      scount ++;
    }
  }

  printf("total number of lines: %d\n", lcount);
  printf("total number of characters: %d \n", ccount);
  printf("total number of non-whitespace characters: %d \n", scount );
  printf("total number of words: %d \n", wcount);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: once you've decided how you define a word (eg. a sequence of lower and or upper case letters, vs. an upper/lower case letter followed by all lower-case, vs. alphanumeric, vs. ...), track whether the current character matches the pattern or does not. Transitions of the pattern matching state indicate the start/end of a word. Count the number of start/end pairs.

Comment: this has been answered many many times on SO.  suggest performing a bit of research.

Comment: `words per-line = #whitespace_breaks + 1` and remember, you need to consider any sequence of whitespace characters `space,tab,etc..` (or multiples thereof) as a single whitespace_break for the purpose of computing the number of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are a number of ways to do this, here is a short concise example that reads from `stdin`, you can simply change `stdin` to `infile` for your purposes (after opening `infile`). This does not count an empty-string (`'\n'` alone) as a word. You can rework this to fit your needs. It contains comments explaining the logic. Let me know if you have questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char *line = NULL;  /* pointer to use with getline ()  */
    char *p = NULL;     /* pointer to parse getline return */
    ssize_t read = 0;   /* actual chars read per-line      */
    size_t n = 0;       /* max chars to read (0 - no limit)*/
    int spaces = 0;     /* counter for spaces and newlines */
    int total = 0;      /* counter for total words read    */

    printf ("\nEnter a line of text (or ctrl+d to quit)\n");

    while (printf ("\n input: ") && (read = getline (&line, &n, stdin)) != -1) 
    {
        /* strip trailing '\n' or '\r' */
        while (line[read-1] == '\n' || line[read-1] == '\r')
            line[--read] = 0;

        spaces = 0;
        p = line;

        if (read > 0) {        /* read = 0 covers '\n' case (blank line with [enter])  */
            while (*p) {                            /* for each character in line      */
                if (*p == '\t' || *p == ' ') {      /* if space,       */
                    while (*p == '\t' || *p == ' ') /* read all spaces */
                        p++;
                    spaces += 1;                    /* consider sequence of spaces 1   */
                } else
                    p++;                            /* if not space, increment pointer */
            }
            total += spaces + 1;                    /* words per-line = spaces + 1     */
        }

        printf (" chars read: %2zd,  spaces: %2d,  words: %2d,  total: %3d   | '%s'\n",
                read, spaces, (spaces > 0) ? spaces+1 : 0, 
                total, (read > 1) ? line : "[enter]");
    }

    printf ("\n\n  Total words read: %d\n\n", total);

    return 0;

}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/countwords

Enter a line of text (or ctrl+d to quit)

 input: my dog has fleas
 chars read: 16,  spaces:  3,  words:  4,  total:   4   | 'my dog has fleas'

 input:
 chars read:  0,  spaces:  0,  words:  0,  total:   4   | '[enter]'

 input: fee fi fo fum
 chars read: 13,  spaces:  3,  words:  4,  total:   8   | 'fee fi fo fum'

 input:

  Total words read: 8
```

**Note:** to expand the whitespace characters recognized, you can include the `ctype.h` header and make use of the `isspace()` function instead of simply checking for `spaces` and `tabs` as is done above. The omission is by intent to limit the required header files to `stdio.h`.

Comment: Thank you! Your code makes it clear! However, my code now seems to read your text fine with the right amount of spaces, words, and characters read yet when I open a huge document it doesnt give me the correct amount of words. It only seems to work with small texts. Any reasons why?

Comment: The only issue I could see if that you are overflowing `int`, Try redefining `spaces` and `total` as `long` instead of `int`. There is nothing we are allocating that would need reallocating for long documents.  Let me know if that corrects the issue.